# Sum up with decimals from $.each loop with increment function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got code, where JS do sum up values from inputs from table use $.each function, all it`s ok but not decimals. Values in inputs gots decimal, but results are only integers. Its working without incremen function

Here is my code:

```
    var summaryNetto = 0;
    var summaryVat = 0;
    var summary = 0;



    $('#products > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

        summaryNetto += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singlePriceSummaryNetto"]').val());
        summaryVat += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singleVatSummary"]').val());
        summary += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singleSummaryBrutto"]').val());

    })

        console.log('summaryNetto: '+summaryNetto);
        console.log('summaryVat: '+summaryVat);
        console.log('summary: '+summary);
```

And here is result

```
summaryNetto: 1333
summaryVat: 0
summary: 1333
```

I put into inputs values value = 1333.33.

I tested it without increment function, of course taking values ​​from the inputs through JS and it works. If I use the increment function of a previously set variable, e.g. var summary = 0; unfortunately doesn't add a decimal value.

```
 $(document).on("keyup click", 'td > input', function() {

        const format = (num, decimals) => num.toLocaleString('pl-PL', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                    });

          var row = $(this).closest("tr");

        var quantity = row.find("input[name='quantity']").val();
        var singlePriceNetto = row.find("input[name='singlePriceNetto']").val();
        var singlePriceSummaryNetto = quantity * singlePriceNetto;
        row.find('input[name="singlePriceSummaryNetto"]').val(format(singlePriceSummaryNetto));

        var singleVat = row.find("input[name='singleVat']").val();
        var singleVatSummary = (singlePriceSummaryNetto * singleVat.replace('%', '')) / 100;
        row.find('input[name="singleVatSummary"]').val(format(singleVatSummary));

        var singleSummaryBrutto = singlePriceSummaryNetto + singleVatSummary;
        row.find('input[name="singleSummaryBrutto"]').val(format(singleSummaryBrutto));

        var summaryNetto = 0;
        var summaryVat = 0;
        var summary = 0;



        $('#products > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

            summaryNetto += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singlePriceSummaryNetto"]').val());
            summaryVat += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singleVatSummary"]').val());
            summary += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singleSummaryBrutto"]').val());

        })

            console.log('summaryNetto: '+summaryNetto);
            console.log('summaryVat: '+summaryVat);
            console.log('summary: '+summary);

        $('span#summaryNetto').empty();
        $('span#summaryNetto').append(format(summaryNetto) + 'zł');
        $('span#summaryVat').empty();
        $('span#summaryVat').append(format(summaryVat) + 'zł');
        $('span#summary').empty();
        $('span#summary').append(format(summary) + 'zł');

    })
```

***************OK SO CORRECT CODE IS**********************

```
var summaryNetto = 0;
var summaryVat = 0;
var summary = 0;



$('#products > tbody  > tr').each(function() {

    summaryNetto += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singlePriceSummaryNetto"]').val().replace(',', '.'));
    summaryVat += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singleVatSummary"]').val().replace(',', '.'));
    summary += parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="singleSummaryBrutto"]').val().replace(',', '.'));

})

    console.log('summaryNetto: '+summaryNetto);
    console.log('summaryVat: '+summaryVat);
    console.log('summary: '+summary);
```

*************CODE WITH CLEARED WHITESPACES FOR POLAND******************

```
var summaryNetto = 0;
var summaryVat = 0;
var summary = 0;



$('#products > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    singlePriceSummaryNetto = $(this).find('input[name="singlePriceSummaryNetto"]').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    summaryNetto += parseFloat(singlePriceSummaryNetto.replace(',','.'));
    singleVatSummary = $(this).find('input[name="singleVatSummary"]').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    summaryVat += parseFloat(singleVatSummary.replace(',', '.'));
    singleSummaryBrutto = $(this).find('input[name="singleSummaryBrutto"]').val().replace(/\s+/g, '');
    summary += parseFloat(singleSummaryBrutto.replace(',', '.'));

})


$('span#summaryNetto').empty();
$('span#summaryNetto').append(format(summaryNetto) + 'zł');
$('span#summaryVat').empty();
$('span#summaryVat').append(format(summaryVat) + 'zł');
$('span#summary').empty();
$('span#summary').append(format(summary) + 'zł');
```

Comment: `parseFloat('1333.33')` is `1333.33`, so you must be doing something wrong with the dot.

Comment: Yes, I use the function: 
        const format = (num, decimals) => num.toLocaleString('pl-PL', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
            maximumFractionDigits: 2,
                    });
 which throws the result into the input before downloading to the increment function so in inputs value is 1333,33 it is wrong ? but there everything is fine. I added code to question.

Comment: I'm Polish myself and as you know, in Poland we use comma as a fraction separator. You got your answer - `toLocaleString()` for `pl-PL` converts dot to a comma :)

Comment: So how to "retransform" this to dot ? i need comma upper... to display value correctly

Comment: I added the answer for that. If you want to have pretty numbers in the inputs, study them for a couple of languages and just make sure it's converted to `123.45` format. For the good start, simple `number.replace(',', '.')` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your usage of `toLocaleString()` for Polish language. In Poland, the fraction separator character is a comma, not a period.

Therefore, `parseFloat('1333,33')` is `1333`. Mystery solved.

If you are interested in further improvement, you can run the following code to see what are the actual formats:

```js
const languages = ['ar-SA', 'bn-BD', 'bn-IN', 'cs-CZ', 'da-DK', 'de-AT', 'de-CH', 'de-DE', 'el-GR', 'en-AU', 'en-CA', 'en-GB', 'en-IE', 'en-IN', 'en-NZ', 'en-US', 'en-ZA', 'es-AR', 'es-CL', 'es-CO', 'es-ES', 'es-MX', 'es-US', 'fi-FI', 'fr-BE', 'fr-CA', 'fr-CH', 'fr-FR', 'he-IL', 'hi-IN', 'hu-HU', 'id-ID', 'it-CH', 'it-IT', 'jp-JP', 'ko-KR', 'nl-BE', 'nl-NL', 'no-NO', 'pl-PL', 'pt-BR', 'pt-PT', 'ro-RO', 'ru-RU', 'sk-SK', 'sv-SE', 'ta-IN', 'ta-LK', 'th-TH', 'tr-TR', 'zh-CN', 'zh-HK', 'zh-TW'];

console.log(languages.reduce((result, language) => ({...result, [language]: (12345.6789).toLocaleString(language, {maximumFractionDigits: 20})}), {}));
```

The result is:

```
{
    "ar-SA": "١٢٬٣٤٥٫٦٧٨٩",
    "bn-BD": "১২,৩৪৫.৬৭৮৯",
    "bn-IN": "১২,৩৪৫.৬৭৮৯",
    "cs-CZ": "12 345,6789",
    "da-DK": "12.345,6789",
    "de-AT": "12 345,6789",
    "de-CH": "12’345.6789",
    "de-DE": "12.345,6789",
    "el-GR": "12.345,6789",
    "en-AU": "12,345.6789",
    "en-CA": "12,345.6789",
    "en-GB": "12,345.6789",
    "en-IE": "12,345.6789",
    "en-IN": "12,345.6789",
    "en-NZ": "12,345.6789",
    "en-US": "12,345.6789",
    "en-ZA": "12 345,6789",
    "es-AR": "12.345,6789",
    "es-CL": "12.345,6789",
    "es-CO": "12.345,6789",
    "es-ES": "12.345,6789",
    "es-MX": "12,345.6789",
    "es-US": "12,345.6789",
    "fi-FI": "12 345,6789",
    "fr-BE": "12 345,6789",
    "fr-CA": "12 345,6789",
    "fr-CH": "12 345,6789",
    "fr-FR": "12 345,6789",
    "he-IL": "12,345.6789",
    "hi-IN": "12,345.6789",
    "hu-HU": "12 345,6789",
    "id-ID": "12.345,6789",
    "it-CH": "12’345.6789",
    "it-IT": "12.345,6789",
    "jp-JP": "12 345,6789",
    "ko-KR": "12,345.6789",
    "nl-BE": "12.345,6789",
    "nl-NL": "12.345,6789",
    "no-NO": "12 345,6789",
    "pl-PL": "12 345,6789",
    "pt-BR": "12.345,6789",
    "pt-PT": "12 345,6789",
    "ro-RO": "12.345,6789",
    "ru-RU": "12 345,6789",
    "sk-SK": "12 345,6789",
    "sv-SE": "12 345,6789",
    "ta-IN": "12,345.6789",
    "ta-LK": "12,345.6789",
    "th-TH": "12,345.6789",
    "tr-TR": "12.345,6789",
    "zh-CN": "12,345.6789",
    "zh-HK": "12,345.6789",
    "zh-TW": "12,345.6789"
}
```

You can see that the first three languages look very exotic, so I'm going to let them be for now. As for the others, you can see that they use many combinations of periods, commas and spaces.

I have written a function that converts any locale string number (client's locale by default) to an actual number. In other words, it's a reverse of `toLocaleString()`.

```js
function numberFromLocaleString(localeString, locale = undefined) {
    const [, thousandSeparator, fractionSeparator] = (12345.6).toLocaleString(locale).match(/12(.*)345(.*)6/);

    return parseFloat([...String(localeString.replace(/\s+/g, ''))].map(character => character.replace(thousandSeparator, '')).join('').replace(fractionSeparator, '.'));
}
```

Tests:

```js
numberFromLocaleString('1') // 1, uses client's locale
numberFromLocaleString('12.34', 'en-US') // 12.34
numberFromLocaleString('12 345,6789', 'pl-PL') // 12345.6789
numberFromLocaleString('-12 345,6789', 'pl-PL') // -12345.6789
numberFromLocaleString('-12’345.6789', 'de-CH') // -12345.6789
numberFromLocaleString('123.456', 'en-US') // 123.456
numberFromLocaleString('123,456', 'en-US') // 123456
```

Keep in mind that I'm just removing all white space from the input number before parsing the locale one. That's because the space separator that exists in some languages (including Polish) is not a regular space. It's a non-breaking space and I don't see anyone actually typing it.

Comment: So how to "retransform" this to dot ? i need comma upper... to display value correctly

Comment: I'm afraid there's no built-in way to do that. But you could write your own implementation by parsing some number, like `12345.6789` and analyze the structure of `toLocaleNumber()` output for that one. You could figure out the format for most languages that way. It's not super simple, as these formats are really different for various languages.

Comment: So for example, if some language returns `12,345.6789`, you can compare it to `12345.6789` and interpret it as: ok, so I can safely remove the comma for that language. If course I'm talking about automated parsing.

Comment: Yeah but it is only for Poland, so ok :) replace made the jod.

Comment: There is another problem, only up to 1000 is ok, becouse next make whitespace like 10 000 and js handle it as 10 not 10000, any idea ?

Comment: I'm updating my answer, give me a minute, because it's pretty long :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code

```js
var totalValue = 0;

$('div').each(function() {
    var inputEl = $(this).find('input[type="text"]');
    var rawInputElValue = inputEl.val();
    // replace invalid charaacters like whitespaces
    rawInputElValue = rawInputElValue.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var inputElValue = parseFloat(rawInputElValue);
    totalValue += inputElValue;
});

$('#total').val(totalValue)
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input1" value="10 000.1">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input2" value="20 000 200.2">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="input3" value="3.3">
</div>
total: <input type="text" id="total">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, ok this works. But do that with increment and each function.

Comment: Problem solved but btw, here is the updated answer using $.each ;)

Comment: There is another problem, only up to 1000 is ok, becouse next make whitespace like 10 000 and js handle it as 10 not 10000, any idea ?

Comment: Yop, checkout my updated answer. As a note, this is also here you could handle your problem with dot and comma.